# Unity FSM which is controlled by Enums, Not Transitioning with Delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, observer-pattern, fsm

I'm using a Finite State Machine (FSM) in Unity3d to control my character's behavior. I have two states for this case: Wait and Idle. The FSM should transition from Wait to Idle after a set amount of time when an event is triggered. However, the transitions aren't working correctly.

When I run the game, the first state that's entered is Wait, and "WAIT" is logged to the console which is ok. **After a certain amount of time** (10.0f), "AFTER" should be logged to the console, indicating that the transition from Wait to Idle has occurred. But before that, "OUT" is logged to the console, indicating that the exit of the Wait state which means transition from Wait to Idle has occurred without the delay(10.0f ). and after that, after the delay "AFTER" is logged to the console. I was expecting "OUT" to write after "AFTER". However, this isn't happening. Here's the code for the Wait state:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaitState : CharacterStates
{
public override void EnterState(CharacterFSM fsm)
{
    fsm.OnCharacterIdle.Invoke();
    Debug.Log("WAIT");
}

public override void UpdateState(CharacterFSM fsm)
{
    if (fsm.executingState == ExecutingState.WAIT)
    {
        Debug.Log("waiting.....");
    }
    else
    {
        ExitState(fsm);
    }
}

public override void ExitState(CharacterFSM fsm)
{
    Debug.Log("OUT");
    if(fsm.executingState == ExecutingState.IDLE)
    {
        fsm.SwitchState(fsm.idleState);
    }
}
}
```

while all this is going on "waiting....." is never logged to the console. Here's the code for CharacterFSM:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public enum ExecutingState
{
 IDLE,
 WALK,
 SPRINT,

 WAIT
}
[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class CharacterFSM : MonoBehaviour
{
 #region FSM
 public ExecutingState executingState;
 public CharacterStates currentState;

 public IdleState idleState = new IdleState();
 public WalkState walkState = new WalkState();
 public SprintState sprintState = new SprintState();
 public WaitState waitState = new WaitState();
 #endregion

void OnEnable()
{
    EventManager.OnLevelAfterStart.AddListener(InvokeMethod);
}
void OnDisable()
{
    EventManager.OnLevelAfterStart.RemoveListener(InvokeMethod);
}

void Start()
{
    executingState = ExecutingState.WAIT;
    currentState = waitState;
    currentState.EnterState(this);
}

void InvokeMethod()
{
    Invoke("StartLevelAfterCamMove", 10.0f);
}

void StartLevelAfterCamMove()
{
    EventManager.OnNpcGetSmart.Invoke();
    Debug.Log("AFTER");
    executingState = ExecutingState.IDLE;
}

void Update()
{
    if(!GameManager.Instance.IsLevelStarted)    return;
    if(GameManager.Instance.IsLevelFail || GameManager.Instance.IsLevelSuccess)     return;
    
    if(FsmManager.Instance.IsCharacterCommunicating)
    {
        executingState = ExecutingState.IDLE;
    }
    else
    {
        if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                executingState = ExecutingState.SPRINT;
            }
            else 
                executingState = ExecutingState.WALK;
        }
        else
        {
            executingState = ExecutingState.IDLE;
        }

    }

    currentState.UpdateState(this);
}

 public void SwitchState(CharacterStates nextState)
 {
     currentState = nextState;
     currentState.EnterState(this);
 }
}
```

As you can see I used enums to control the transition between states.

I'm not sure why the transition isn't happening after a certain amount of time. Sorry if there is any confusing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not looking into this too deep, you seem to be in the `WAIT` state while you do something with your camera. During this time your `Update` instantly retruns meaning that you never reach the `UpdateState` call that would be printing the "waiting....." message. It's not very clear if OUT is actually logged after 10s or not. If I understand it correctly you probably call the ExitState when you make the NPC smart. In this case I would expect OUT to be written before AFTER.

Comment: @Voidsay No, OUT is not logged after 10s. It is logged just after the OnLevelAfterStart event called. About ExitState, "executingState = ExecutingState.IDLE;" makes it called through the if case inside UpdateState, so it has nothing to do with the OnNpcGetSmart event.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In this case I would guess that on the first update loop you go thru all the conditions and arrive at the state change. Since it instantly switches states to `IDLE` the updated state never shows waiting. You can check this theory by adding a debug log at line 77 of your CharacterFSM script.

Comment: @Voidsay Yes i tried it, and it worked as you said. I totally understand. Thank you very much for helping.